# which sdk for development I need to use for my app for android 2.1

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am very confused about the build target. We can define the application's  target and min & max target in manifest file.let's take an example :--

I want to build an application which should run in android 2.1 (API 7) and should be run to in the latest version of android.

I know that i should write like this:--

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

My big question is:--

**which sdk for development i should use?**

**Is any problem arise if i use API 17 for my app whose minsdkversion is API 7?**

**Can I use fragment and all that stuff in API 7 if i use API 17 for development?**

Answer (score 1):

**Following are statements straight from android devloper site..**

```
android:minSdkVersion
```

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

```
android:targetSdkVersion
```

An integer designating the API Level that the application is targetting.

With this attribute set, the application says that it is able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion), but was explicitly tested to work with the version specified here. Specifying this target version allows the platform to disable compatibility settings that are not required for the target version (which may otherwise be turned on in order to maintain forward-compatibility) or enable newer features that are not available to older applications. This does not mean that you can program different features for different versions of the platform—it simply informs the platform that you have tested against the target version and the platform should not perform any extra work to maintain forward-compatibility with the target version.

For more information [refer this URL:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: i understand your point but please tell me about my real confusion.which project build target should i use?

Comment: First.. **why minSdkVersion**. Straight forward answer.. once set your application will not be installed in phones less that specified....Second why **targetSdkVersion**.. specifies application can run on older versions but was highly tested on specified version...

Comment: which project build target should use for building my application? (i mean the build target we should choose when in eclipse we right click on project and goes to properties and click on android and we get all the android version to build the app. i think you understand my point... please help me)

Comment: Well, it depends on your requirement completely.. higher sdkVersion provides more features.. Lets take an example.. you are aiming at creating applications with your base phone say Samsung Galaxy Duos... which is Gingerbread OS.. so you targetSdkVersion like 2.3 or if for IceCreamSandwich like 4.0

Comment: What I meant is set target as per your base phone you selected

Comment: i think you didnt get my point.. in eclipse if i right click on project and then select properties and then go to android ,there are many android version to choose.. I want to know if i use the latest sdk for development is it ok? is any problem arise if i use API 17 for my app whose minsdkversion is API 7?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30036/discussion-between-kailash-dabhi-and-crusader)

Answer (score 1):

Build target setting in `project.properties` controls compile-time platform version. Manifest SDK versions control installation time and runtime platform features.

Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) suggests to use the most recent build target:

> We strongly recommend using the most recent version of the API.

In practice, use at least the same version of the SDK to compile against as is your `targetSdkVersion`. There's practically no harm in using a higher compile-time SDK version than your target.

Of course, you cannot call APIs that are not available in the runtime platform. If you use higher API level calls than your `minSdkVersion`, you'll need to check at runtime that the underlying platform API level is high enough. At compile time, [Android lint will give you errors or warnings](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) if you attempt to use APIs that are not available in your `minSdkVersion`.

To use Fragments in API levels <11, use the [Android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).